# Efficient way of adding attributes to HTML using Flask with fewer lines of code to select element?

Tags: html, flask, attributes, jinja2

I have a `select` element which I would like to populate from a database if this information already exists. For example, this is what I did for gender:

```
<select class="form-control" id="gender">
    <option value="-5">Not Selected</option>
    {% if current_user.gender == 0 %}
      <option value="0" selected>Male</option>
    {% else %}
      <option value="0">Male</option>
    {% endif %}

    {% if current_user.gender == 1 %}
        <option value="1" selected>Female</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value="1">Female</option>
    {% endif %}
</select>
```

Now I have another `select` element with 6 different options (all with integer values 0, 1, 2 ... 5). Is there a way to make it more concise instead of writing 30 lines of code like this with if statement for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is for loop in jinja2 templating.

If you have for example a python list which contain all of select options:

```
options = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', ...]

<select class="form-control" id="gender">

{% for option in options %}
<option value="{{ loop.index }}" 
{% if current_user.gender == loop.index %}
selected
{% endif %}
>{{ option }}</option>
{% endfor %}
<option value="-5">Not Selected</option>

</select>
```

loop.index represent the current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)

This is one example, but there is other when you iterating through objects which you've gotten from a database:

```
objects = [object1, object2, object3, ...]

<select class="form-control" id="gender">

{% for object in objects %}
<option value="{{ object.value }}" 
{% if object.value == current_user.gender %}
selected
{% endif %}
>{{ object.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
<option value="-5">Not Selected</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Would I define `options` in my python code and just pass it to the HTML page?

Comment: Yes, you should define a list of your option values in your python code or store somewhere in the database and then get them from the database. If you use Flask, I'm pretty sure that you are using render_template. For example return render_template('page.html', options=options, objects=objects) and that python variable will be available in html. Also you can use jinja assignment tag: {% set options = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'] %} before for loop in the code above, and then you don't need to define python options in your flask route.